# Separar lista de palabras de una consulta en MySql y NodeJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, ejs, sequelize

tengo una tabla en mysql con este campo en formato Text o texto:

| Claves |
| --- |
| palabra1,palabra2,palabra3 |
|  |

y tengo una pagina donde quiero mostrar cada palabra por separado en botones, de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al hacer la consulta (usando Sequelize) para traer la información de ese campo, me trae todo en un botón y termina viéndose de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, queria saber si habria alguna forma de separar cada palabra para mostrarlas en cada boton, mi codigo para hacer la consulta y posteriormente mostrar esos datos, es el siguiente:

```
exports.book = async(req,res) =>{
const books = await Libros.findByPk(req.params.libroId);
res.render('book',{books});
```

}

En este caso hago la consulta con mi modelo de Libros para traer toda la información específicamente de un libro.

Ahora para mostrar estos datos en botones lo hago de la siguiente forma (utilizo las plantillas de ejs para renderizar la información) :

```
<button value="<%= books.claves %>" name="searchCl1"> <%= books.claves %> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que se me ocurre es que uses split()

Algo como esto:

```
exports.book = async(req,res) =>{
let books = await Libros.findByPk(req.params.libroId);

books = books.claves.split(",");

res.render('book',{books});
```

[image: resultado]

Y en tu EJS lo renderizas así:

```
<% books.forEach(function(books) { %>
    <button value="<%= books.claves %>" name="searchCl1"> <%= books.claves %> </button>
<% }); %>
```